# Can I bind/set a dependency property of type Type to DataType of a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, types, datatemplate

I am creating Custom User Control. My goal is to make the control reusable.
I am using ItemsControl, here is XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemSource , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyItemsControlWithButtons}}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type=typeOf(DataTemplateType)????}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="instruction" Content="{Binding Path=DataTemplateControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyItemsControlWithButtons}}}"/>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DDDDDD" TargetName="instruction" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" TargetName="instruction" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is control:MyItemsControlWithButtons

```
public partial class DraggableItemsControlWithButtons : UserControl
    {
        public DraggableItemsControlWithButtons()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTemplateTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DataTemplateType), typeof(Type), typeof(DraggableItemsControlWithButtons), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public Type DataTemplateType
        {
            get { return (Type)GetValue(DataTemplateTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataTemplateTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ItemSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DraggableItemsControlWithButtons), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public IEnumerable ItemSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTemplateControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DataTemplateControl), typeof(Control), typeof(DraggableItemsControlWithButtons), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public Control DataTemplateControl
        {
            get { return (Control)GetValue(DataTemplateControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataTemplateControlProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I want to bind/set DataTemplateType to DataType of the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate's DataTemplate

How can I achieve it?

Thank you

Comment: It isn't necessary to set the DataType at all here, because you have explicitly assigned the DataTemplate to the ItemTemplate property. There is no automatoc selection by data type.

Comment: What you probably want is to be able to set the ItemTemplate externally. Create a depedency property of type DataTemplate in your UserControl, and bind the ItemsSource ItemTemplate to it.

Comment: @Clemens Can you provide sample code?

Comment: Exactly like you've created the ItemsSource property and bound to it in the UserControl's XAML. Not sure however if that is necssary at all, since your current DataTemplate already contains a ContentControl that hosts the DataTemplateControl. What else would you do in a different ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probaby simplify your control by replacing the `DataTemplateControl` property by an `ItemTemplate` property. And to complete the similarity with an ItemsControl, rename the `ItemSource` property to `ItemsSource`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable),
        typeof(DraggableItemsControlWithButtons));

public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate),
        typeof(DraggableItemsControlWithButtons));

public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

The ItemsControl in the UserControl's XAML would look like this:

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
    ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

You would then assign the ItemTemplate just like in any other control with an `ItemTemplate` property:

```
<local:DraggableItemsControlWithButtons ItemSource="{Binding ...}">
    <local:DraggableItemsControlWithButtons.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:DraggableItemsControlWithButtons.ItemTemplate>
</local:DraggableItemsControlWithButtons>
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to "hide"/encapsualte ItemTemplate is Triggers & Style. I want to avoid defining the same in several places

Comment: Not sure what that means. Now you have a DataTemplateControl property, which must be set. The "usual" approach is to have an ItemTemplate property.

Comment: I added DataTemplate.Triggers to my question to show what I meant

Comment: Ok, then you should probably keep your approach. You understood that setting the DataType of your ItemTemplate has no effect and isn't even necessary?

Comment: sorry one more question: how do I set a User Control to a DependenceProperty?

Comment: figured it out, no worries